# Неизвестный формат у получаемого файла, octet-stream

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: никак не удаётся получить файл с удалённого сервера. 
Какой формат файла - не известно (подозреваю, что json или xml, но кто ж его знает на самом деле).

Для начала запрашиваю файл.

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $q);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $b);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo curl_error($curl);
    //print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
```

Далее пошли танцы с бубном:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($out));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($out));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($out);
```

В итоге получаю пустой файл без расширения. Однако сниффер ловит какой-то контент. Сохраняется он, если запрашивать на прямую, как байт-код:

```
789c ab56 4a2d 2aca 2f52 b2aa 564a ce4f
4955 b232 3432 30d4 514a 492d 4e56 b252
52aa ad05 00b2 7b0a 03
```

Далее, поиски привели меня к тому, что всё это дело заодно и сжато при помощи [вот этой штуки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib)

После прогона ответа от сервера через **gzdecode()** var_dump() говорит false. Отдаётся пустой файл, но с именем скрипта, на который отправляется, собственно, запрос.

Попытки поиграться с content-type в заголовках не привели ровно ни к чему.

Собственно, вопрос, возможно ли как-то всё таки узнать формат файла, и почему в итоге он становится пустым? В какую сторону копать? Заранее спасибо.

**UPD**

Провтыкал заголовок. Добавил `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

Стал возвращаться код файла.  Сейчас буду пытаться распознать.

**UPD 2**.

И снова. Тип данных: двоичный файл.

Comment: А спросить у владельца удаленного сайта или его обслуги нельзя?

Comment: а в браузере нормально работает?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, нельзя. 

@FarkhodDaniyarov, это данные, приходящие к флешу. По сути, в браузере, если смотреть в консоли, на данный момент получаю ответ в следующем виде:

`789c ab56 4a2d 2aca 2f52 b2aa 564a ce4f
4955 b232 3432 30d4 514a 492d 4e56 b252
52aa ad05 00b2 7b0a 03`

Comment: А когда вы `curl` получаете данные, то какие заголовки еще получаете от удаленного сервера?